# How to constraint the center of a UIButton object to its superview without Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

G'day, All! Excuse me for being a tad troublesome, but despite all my efforts, I have failed to get auto layout stuff to work in my code. I am building my iOS app without Xcode, mainly on the command line. As a result, I think it might cause some issues relevant to Auto Layout. Please find below the simplest attempt to constraint the center of a UIButton object to its superview.

So far I have had a go at various Layout techniques including Anchoring, NSLayotConstraint constraintWithItem: and VFL. None of the above has had any effect on the position of the subviews. I get neither compile nor runtime errors. TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints is OFF. Honestly, it beats me what makes my code not behave as expected. What's more, I have gone through numerous Auto Layout examples available online. Any help would be genuinely appreciated.

````
{
  NSLayoutConstraint    *constraint;

  [aButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
  constraint =
    [NSLayoutConstraint
      constraintWithItem:aButton
      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
      toItem:aButton.superview
      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
      multiplier:1.0f
      constant:0.0f];
  constraint.active = YES;
  [aButton.superview addConstraint:constraint];
  constraint =
    [NSLayoutConstraint
      constraintWithItem:aButton
      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
      toItem:aButton.superview
      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
      multiplier:1.0f
      constant:0.0f];
  constraint.active = YES;
  [aButton.superview addConstraint:constraint];
}```
````

Comment: Do not call addConstraint. Just setting active to YES is enough.

Comment: What does “I am building my iOS app without Xcode, mainly on the command line” mean?

Comment: Are you adding the button to its superview before you create and activate the constraints?

Comment: @matt Many thanks for your suggestion, yet it has made no difference. What I mean by that is that I am compiling my iOS project using only clang and I do not utilize Interface Builder either.

Comment: It is fine not to use Interface Builder. But I don't see how you can have an iOS project without Xcode.

Comment: The thing is that your code would _normally_ work, so you need to tell us about what is _not_ normal in what you are doing. You have not told us except for those mysterious words about not using Xcode.

Comment: @vacawama Yes, I am. Actual, when I log the output of [self.view constraints], it says that everything is in order.
```May  5 08:15:13 10 Autolayout[69346]: Constraints:
 (
     <NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000048bcf0 UIRoundedRectButton:0x7fc05a42dcf0'Dismiss'.centerX == UIView:0x7fc05a42db10.centerX   (active)>,
     <NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000048be80 UIRoundedRectButton:0x7fc05a42dcf0'Dismiss'.centerY == UIView:0x7fc05a42db10.centerY   (active)>
 )```

Comment: @matt To clear it up a little bit, I should walk you through my building process. First up, I define classes and methods in source (.m) and header (.h) files. Then, I compile them into an executable by using clang with necessary options. Afterwards, I get the executable installed on the iOS simulator. That is it. What I get as a result is a perfectly functional app except for my views and controllers remaining unconstrained. My hope is that the explanation is straightforward enough. Once again, I do appreciate your time and desire to help.

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with that way of doing things. It sounds to me like this is not a real app executable with a normal set of lifetime events. Check to see whether your view controller's `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is being called. If not, that's the problem.

Comment: @matt Having followed your guidance, I have firmed up a call to the viewDidLayoutSubviews being made. Therefore, there must be something else that is causing the hitch.

Comment: So where do the buttons appear if not in the center?

Comment: @matt In the left top corner at (0,0).

Comment: @KirillKozlov - are you adding your button to the "main view* of the view controller? Or adding it to a subview? If the latter, are you sure ***that*** subview has proper constraints setup?

Comment: @DonMag I have added the button to its superview which is the root view of a view controller.

Comment: @KirillKozlov - a little tough to figure out what might be wrong, seeing only that snippet of your code. Take a look at this: https://gist.github.com/DonMag/afd8797613545d02d4dbf5ec6d04804d ... should be all you need to launch a view controller with a centered `UIButton`

Comment: @DonMag I thank you most graciously for having gone to the trouble of writing the code for my sake. In spite of my gazillionth attempt to make Auto Layout function, it has come to nothing. For some reason, as noted above, I am not receiving any compilation or runtime errors. Over and above, my log records state that the constraints exist and the right views are involved. Despite all that, when I launch the app, the button is positioned in the top left corner. That is driving me mad.

Comment: @KirillKozlov - this makes me wonder about your process of *"... compile them into an executable ... installed on the iOS simulator ..."*. It sounds like perhaps you're missing some necessary information for it to be an actual iOS app. You're logging the constraints for the button... what do you get if you log the frames and bounds of the root view and the window (such as in `viewDidAppear()`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the hitch was brought on by my linking the wrong SDK. Instead of iPhoneSimulator.sdk, I should have utilized iPhoneSimulator12.1.sdk.

```
-isysroot $(ISYS_ROOT)
ISYS_ROOT = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.1.sdk
```

A million thanks to everyone who strove to help.